# SQL - Query Select Joins through multiple tables

Tags: sql, cross-join

Here is the situation:

I search for Persons with ID (`empr`.`empr_cb`)
that has bill(s) to pay (`transactions`.`montant`)
this refers to `transactions`.`compte_id`
which is identical to `comptes`.`id_compte`
this refers to `comptes`.`proprio.id` 
which is identical to `empr`.`id_empr`
that would give us the Person ID (`empr`.`empr_cb`)

I tried this, but I don't know what joins to set (cross Join?):

```
SELECT `empr`.`empr_cb`,`transactions`.`montant`
FROM `empr`,`comptes`,`transactions`
WHERE `transactions`.`montant` > `0` 
AND `transactions`.`encaissement` = `0` 
AND `transactions`.compte_id` = `comptes`.`id_compte` 
AND `comptes`.`proprio_id` = `id_empr`
```

Any ideas how to put the joins?

Answer (score 3):

This query is already using implicit `INNER JOIN`s. It can be rewritten this way:

```
SELECT empr.empr_cb
     , transactions.montant
  FROM empr
  JOIN comptes ON comptes.proprio_id = empr.id_empr
  JOIN transactions ON transactions.compte_id = comptes.id_compte
 WHERE transactions.encaissement = 0
   AND transactions.montant > 0
```

Comment: That's perfect! its the LOIN function structure that I did not get right. Merci Beaucoup benoit